# Trying to change image from the user's input in prompt box

Tags: html, image, function, getelementbyid

I'm a student, so forgive me I'm still a beginner in javascript, this is actually one of our first lessons. So I'm trying to make a function in which the user inputs a specific number in the prompt box, and the image changes. But for some reason the image doesn't change even if the user enters the correct number.

```
    alert("Welcome user! Let's set up your profile");
    var name = prompt("Enter your name");
    var user = prompt("Enter your username(Prefer not to use your real name!)");
    var add = prompt("Enter your address");
    var age = prompt("Enter your age");
    var sex = parseInt(prompt("Enter your sex (0 if male, 1 if female)"));
    
    document.getElementById("call").innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById("use").innerHTML = "@"+user;
    document.getElementById("home").innerHTML = add;
    document.getElementById("bday").innerHTML = age+" years old";

    function changeImage() {
        if (sex==0) {
            document.getElementById("myImage").src="male.jpg";
        } else if (sex==1) {
            document.getElementById("myImage").src="female.jpg";
        } else {
            alert("You may have entered something above 0 and 1, please try again!");
        } }
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical description of a problem. [ask]

Comment: Where and when is your changeImage function called?